# lost admin toolbar and stock file

Tags: commerce, database, debugging

I am a total Drupal newbie so need advice.

I installed a new module commerce_shipping_postal_code_weight-7.x-1.x-dev, and tried to activate it. I was then advised a couple of other modules needed authorising. I authorised everything and then returned to my home screen.
My left hand column had disappeared which contained my login box, my stock file has disappeared, and so has my admin toolbar.
Logging in using /?q=user doesn't reveal the toolbar, but I am logged in.
I've restored all my files from 24 hours ago with no joy and now am waiting for our ISP to send me a backup database.
The only error message I get is :-

```
    Notice: Undefined index: search_api_views_fulltext in
 views_handler_filter->accept_exposed_input() (line 1273 of
 /homepages/11/d95668464/htdocs/drupaltest/profiles/commerce_kickstart/modules/contrib/views/handlers/views_handler_filter.inc).
 Notice: Undefined index: table in
 entity_views_plugin_row_entity_view->init() (line 20 of
 /homepages/11/d95668464/htdocs/drupaltest/profiles/commerce_kickstart/modules/contrib/entity/views/plugins/entity_views_plugin_row_entity_view.inc).
```

I had only downloaded and enabled the modules, and they had not been used so I have no idea of how I could have prevented it.

Comment: Please check toolbar module is enabled or not by logged in using admin. For direct access of modules page use /admin/modules

Comment: Thank you @Shubham but that didn't work. Apparently the correct path is /modules, however I got HTTP403: FORBIDDEN - The server understood the request, but is refusing to fulfil it.  I was logged in correctly as admin.

Comment: Please check the clean URL is enabled or not. I think all the url's you are accessing using /?q=YOUR_PATH. Also I can confirm that for drupal 7 modules page path is /admin/modules. Try to access as http://YOURSITE.com/?q=admin/modules . Hope it will give you access for that page.

Comment: Thank you, yes it does. It gives me hope that I can now go through and fix things

Comment: Please up my comment it will help me. :P

Comment: How do I mark up a comment @Shubham? I can only see votes for answers.

Answer (score 0):

The fault turned out to be that a lot of modules had become de-selected. A good procedure would probably be to print off a module list with all the selected ones shown, this could then easily be checked by future webmasters.

Answer (score 0):

In a drupal website if multiple users use modules page at a time, than there is a chance of disabling of the modules which are already enabled. In that case most of the drupal features will not be available as in the above case. So, we just need to figure out which one are get disabled and enable them all. We can access modules page directly using /admin/modules or /?q=admin/modules

This will lead you directly to the module listing page, where you can find disabled modules and can enable them.

Comment: Thank you.  Eventually I did just that, but it gave me a huge headache.